# UITableView is laggy and jumps when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

I'm using an UITableView with dynamic cells. Every cell has some buttons, an image and a label. The image's width is equal to tableview width and the height is variable.

I am updating the height of the image in cellForRowAtIndexPath by a function... to respect the aspect ratio. The label can have 1 or more lines.

I'm using heightForRowAtIndexPath to set the height of the cell. I'm calculating it there and return the value.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    let queficient = CGFloat(dataController.Data[indexPath.row].width) / self.view.frame.size.width

    let imgHeight = CGFloat(dataController.Data[indexPath.row].height) / queficient

    return 134 + imgHeight + heightForView(dataController.Data[indexPath.row].description)
}
```

I don't know why the table is a little laggy and jumping when I scroll.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the lag is caused by heightforRowAtIndexPath, why dont you calculate the height for each cell data/indexpath only once, when the image changes?

you should just return dataController.Data[indexPath.row].calculatedCellHeight or something